# show post thumbnail navigation link in in multiply pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a navigation for my WordPress, the navigation gets the title of the pages and display them by title.

Now I want to change the contact title to an image(mail icon of course).

I have add a feature image in the contact page.
I can call the thumbnail with

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

The problem is that the thumbnail image only shows when I'm inside the contact page where the thumbnail is added.

I could add the image in every page that I create, but it must be another better way to do it.

This is my navigation code.

```
 <ul id="nav">
   <?php wp_list_pages('exclude=19&title_li=', 'sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
               </ul>
```

As you see I am excluding page 19, so it wont show in the navigation. 
But i can call the image with the `get_the_post_thumbnail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching i found out that i wasn't that hard at all.

If i want to use the thumbnail from page 19 I just write

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('19'); ?>
```